# Send foreach $_post method to contact form 7

Tags: php, functions, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a list of products generated by Javascript, I need to send them by the POST method via “contact form 7” If the list had 10 items, it would not be too heavy write 10 lines of code with "Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension" but if 50 or 100, it would be a little difficult.

Maybe it would be a solution to do a foreach to $ _POST, but contact form 7 does not allow adding this type of code. How could I integrate it?

Answer (score 1):

-Create a shortcode in wordpress displaying select box with options generated. You can get some ideas from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85159/shortcode-to-create-dynamic-dropdown-box-form-shortcode-attributes)

-now just put new shortcode into contact form

Should work well this way